# How to generate an efficient 128-bit shift on ARM64 with MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, intrinsics

Compiling the following with GCC/Clang on ARM64:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

uint64_t shiftright61(uint64_t lo, uint64_t hi) {
    return ((((__uint128_t) hi) << 64) | lo) >> 61;
}
```

generates the efficient implementation:

```
shiftright61(unsigned long, unsigned long):
        extr    x0, x1, x0, 61
        ret
```

Is there a way to get MSVC to generate this 128-bit shift on ARM64? On x64 the following works to generate the `SHRD` 128-bit shift instruction, but on ARM64 MSVC complains that `__shiftright128` is not defined:

```c
#include <cstdint>
#include <intrin.h>

uint64_t shiftright61(uint64_t lo, uint64_t hi) {
    return __shiftright128(lo, hi, 61);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why the return statement is uint64_t though. Is this a pseudo uint64 where there is actually a low part to the right?

Comment: @Irelia Sorry I should've probably been more specific. The instruction I'm interested in shifts a 128-bit integer to the right by a constant, after which it takes the lower 64 bits as the result. On x64 this is the `shrd` instruction, on ARM it's `extr`.

Answer (score 2):

The following is recognized by the compiler to generate an efficient shift:

```cpp
uint64_t shiftright61(uint64_t lo, uint64_t hi) {
    return (lo >> 61) | (hi << 3);
}
```

```
unsigned __int64 shiftright61(unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64):
        extr        x0,x1,x0,#0x3D
        ret
```

Prior to posting this question I used `+` instead of `|` to combine the low and high shifts, which the optimizer did not recognize.

Interestingly the above is **not** currently recognized on x64, where you must still use `__shiftright128` intrinsic to get the compiler to emit the `SHRD` instruction.